# EF6 Strange Dateproblem / Context.SaveChanges messes up date

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

In my model i have a DateTime object, filled from a WebAPI by a JSON string.

the model.end reads in the debugger:

```
model.end   {13.09.2016 23:59:59}   System.DateTime
```

or in Ticks:

```
model.end.Ticks 636094079999990000  long
```

then i set my Entity endDate to my model.end:

```
appointment.endDate = model.end;
```

store the whole thing with my SaveChanges:

```
appointment.LastEdit = DateTime.Now;
ctx.Appointments.Add(appointment);
ctx.SaveChanges(); 
return appointment; //BreakPointSet
```

at the Breakpoint, the appointment object reads the Correct Date:

```
appointment.endDate {13.09.2016 23:59:59}   System.DateTime
```

When reading the ctx.Appointments.ToList() in the debugger, it also reflects the correct date.

BUT.... when i connect to my Database, and do a read on the Appointments Table, the end date is set to:

```
14.09.2016 00:00:00
```

WHAT?? where comes that extra second from?

Comment: What's the type in the database? My guess is that it's only got a granularity of a second, and that it's rounding to the nearest second on insert...

Comment: SQL Server LocalDB
Data Type: datetime
Length: 8
Precision: 23
Scale: 3

Comment: Just to make sure the problem is not in the code, try `appointment.endDate = new DateTime(model.end.Year, model.end.Month, model.end.Day, 23, 59, 59);`

Comment: @KeyurPATEL just found out that the MilliSeconds is 999, so did a NewDate as you described, and now it works.

Totally overseen the Milliseconds..

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own Question:

```
model.end.Ticks 636094079999990000  long
```

is

```
model.end   {13.09.2016 23:59:59}   System.DateTime
```

but also:

```
model.end.Millisecond   999   int
```

and the Database cant handle milliseconds, so skips to the nearest second.